# How to face many customer specific GUI variants, searching for alternative to Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, report, qml

we're maintaining some Qt applications which are running on Linux and Windows desktops. Now, we want to make the applications more attractive by adding customized forms and reports for each customer or at least groups of customers. There may be 10 or more different versions needed.

As we come from Qt, we are wondering how to manage so many configurations and if there already is a framework/development system that would help us here. We were looking at QML/Qt Quick, WT Toolkit or even NC Reports for the reporting part.
Managing configurations and deriving different versions from a base is not a feature which is discussed or promoted.

- There should be a clean distinction between Display and Application Logic (Model/View)
- Nice would be a textual GUI description, which enables us to release changes in forms or reports without the need to reinstall the whole applications (like QML seems to have that)
- Also nice would be a kind of report generator, that helps to create forms and reports for new customers without the need to code them (and so releases our core developers from boring work)

Has somebody experience with such kind of customer based configurations? It would be nice to have a hint what's the best way to do this in the Qt surrounding.

I know comparisons like http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/topics-ui.html#comparison, but the specific questions that I have are not mentioned.

best regards

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you task you're trying to solve. Did you consider Qt styles?

Comment: Different customers may want to calculate values in reports in a different way. Styles are more for the look and feel, aren't they? If you don't want lot's of switch(customer-id) cases, you may use svn branches for each customers - making maintenance a nightmare. I hope for some more development tool support here.

Comment: If you need customized UIs, I would make sure your UI is as thin as possible (i. e. no business-logic in UI classes, just views and controls), and then have multiple UI forms which you can select either at runtime or at build time. I don't see how any other framework would be better than Qt.

Comment: With Qt, you could use plugins for customizable parts of UI, if you use widgets. With Qt Quick 2 just have different QML UI, with backend which supports all the GUI may need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I learnt from 8 month qt:

- Model/View Architecture is there, for example a tree view that we fill with voyage data. the data is gatheres from several db tables, so we have a good logical distinction.
- We hadn't the time to work us into qml, so we stuck with qt designer. It's quite easy, so we're fine with that. Delivering changes in customer forms without recompile will be a feature for a bigger future rework.
- Same with report generators...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to differentiate applications in three aspects:
1. appearance - if the application only differs in button color, icon image and background themes, qt's style sheet is light and convenient, you can choose to deploy different qss file and load different ones without recoding. if the variance among customers concerns layouts or available widgets (some has buttons, some use combo boxes, .etc), style sheet cannot meet the requirement, QML seems promising in such case.

1. business logic - i'm not sure how "generating reports" differs for different customers, if the reports need to be printed, or saved as document, i don't think qt provides good toolkit (QXXXDocument is not suitable to generate / display large amount of document), html? maybe. And i agree with @hyde that loading different plugins or dynamic libraries can solve this.